# Use input box as a password box to select sheet VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I want to use an input box to enter a password to select a specific sheet in Excel.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub DCAInputSelect()
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Password", "DCA Input Screen")
    Range("T6").Value = myValue
    Sheets("DCA INPUT").Select
End Sub
```

I only want to go to the sheet "DCA INPUT" if the input from the box is `p3t3`

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `if` statement to check the password is p3t3.

```
Sub DCAInputSelect()
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Password", "DCA Input Screen")
    Range("T6").Value = myValue
    If myValue = "p3t3" Then Sheets("DCA INPUT").Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Not part of the original question but I had a similar thing a while ago that gives users 3 attempts at a password, this is how it would look in your case.

```
Sub DCAInputSelect()
   Dim myValue As Variant, i As Integer, f As Integer
   i = 1
   f = 1
   Do While i <> 2
       If f = 4 Then Exit Do
       myValue = InputBox("Enter Password, attempt no " & f & " of 3", "DCA Input Screen")
       Range("A1").Value = myValue
       If myValue = "p3t3" Then
           Sheets("DCA INPUT").Select
           i = 2
       Else
           f = f + 1
       End If
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to make the sheet `xlSheetVeryHidden` and only make it `Visible` once the correct password has been entered as well

Comment: Ahh so simple, i was thinking i would need to use a `case when` or something like that, I'm guessing i can still use `else' for if the incorrect password is entered

Comment: What's the point of using variable `i`? Couldn't you just use `f` and `Do While f <> 4`?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
Sub DCAInputSelect()
    Const pwd As String = "p3t3"
    Dim myValue As Variant

    myValue = InputBox("Enter Password [blank to abort]", "DCA Input Screen")
    Do While myValue <> pwd And myValue <> vbNullString
        MsgBox "Invalid Password", vbCritical
        myValue = InputBox("Enter Password [blank to abort]", "DCA Input Screen")
    Loop
    If myValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Range("T6").value = myValue
    Sheets("DCA INPUT").Select
End Sub
```